# re match a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have some output from a CAS and I want to split up the stuff into three, here is some sample output:

```
' 1+2;\r\n\r(%o2)                                  3\r\n(%i3) '
'?\r\n\r\n\rpos;\r\n\r(%o1)                                  0\r\n(%i2) '
```

I'd like to separate the output into three parts:

1. The part from the beginning of the string to the ';' semi-colon.
2. The part from after the semi-colon to  just *before* the final  `\r\n\(%i\d+\)`
3. The final part to be by itself ie.`\r\n\(%i\d+\)` to always be alone in the final part.

how would I separate them? I'm having trouble creating the code to do that.

EDIT:
I'd like the semicolon to be retained even after separating the sections.

Comment: Would group 2 or 3 include `\r\n\(%i\d+\)`, or is this to be excluded from the matched groups?

Comment: @willOEM group 3 would contain that. it would be the only item in group 3

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have updated my answer accordingly.  You should tweak the wording of your question a bit to make this crystal clear.

Comment: @willOEM unfortunately english isnt my first/only language, but i'v made an effort, let me know if its better.

Comment: No problem, just do the best you can.  You are better at English than I am at any other language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you have requested:

```
re.findall('^([^;]+);(.*)(\r\n\(%i\d+\).+)$', text, re.S)
```

To include the semicolon in the first group, just add it to the grouping parenthesis:

```
re.findall('^([^;]+;)(.*)(\r\n\(%i\d+\).+)$', text, re.S)
```

Comment: you code for the most part works, but it throws away the semicolon after separating the groups, how can i keep the semicolon and still use it as a "boundary", it should remain in the 1st group.

Comment: By adding the semicolon to the parenthesis that define the first group, they will not be excluded from the matched groups.  When you have parenthesis defining match groups, everything outside of them will not be returned.  When there are no parenthesis, then everythng in the regex pattern that matches will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you need regular expressions for this:

```
In [31]: s = '?\r\n\r\n\rpos;\r\n\r(%o1)                                  0\r\n(%i2) '

In [32]: p1, _, p23 = s.partition(';')

In [33]: p2, _, p3 = p23.rpartition('\r\n')

In [34]: p1, p2, p3
Out[34]: ('?\r\n\r\n\rpos', '\r\n\r(%o1)                                  0', '(%i2) ')
```

Comment: the minimalist approach is certainly nice, but i needed the semicolons,